# How to detect when the Chrome browser window is closed using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am trying to detect the following scenarios:

- User navigates away from the web page
- User closes the tab
- User opens a new tab (i.e. visibility is lost on the old tab)
- User closes the browser

I am able to detect all four scenarios above in Safari, Firefox and Chrome, except for "User closes the browser" in Chrome (91.0.4472.114). Currently it does not emit an event which I am able to listen for.

This is my code:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    // do something
}

window.addEventListener('pagehide', function() {
    // do something
}, { capture: true, once: true });

window.addEventListener('unload', function() {
    // do something
}, { capture: true, once: true });

window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function() {
    // do something
}, { capture: true, once: true });

window.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function() {
    if (document.visibilityState === 'hidden') {
        // do something
    }
}, { capture: true} );
```

As far as I can tell, I'm checking everything, but maybe I'm missing something?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Which event from this list do you refer to as *"User closes the browser"*?

Comment: @vsync the problem is the different browsers are inconsistent in how they handle things. For example, my current version of Safari only works with window.onbeforeunload when closing the tab, but Firefox and Chrome are happy to use pagehide. So what I'm doing is trying to use every possible way to detect when the tab/browser closes in the hope that I can cover all browsers. But I'm wondering if I've missed one which is needed for closing the Chrome browser window.